Github - Visual Studio Code - repository not found
I have an issue with Github and Visual Studio Code.
I can clone und manupulate existing repos, but when I try to clone a new repo or push into a new repo, the error "repository not found" shows up.
I also can open the repo directly in VS Code direct access to my github account
It is so strange, that I only cannot clone new repositories...
Anybody a quick answer to that?
Thanks in advance.
Lars

config
camelcase
add remote vom VSC
clone via "git clone" (in different ways)
checking if anything is different to already existing projects.


Adding the following strange happening.
When I do git init and all the rest and then I want to "Publish Branch" as private repo, it is created as an empty repo but with no content.

In the output of VSC it is written:
2024-06-18 15:32:28.515 [warning] git config failed: Failed to execute git
